# Making a node.js application a PEER with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, node-webkit

So, I have a web app that generates large buffers of color information that I want to send to a node application running on another machine in my local network. Web Sockets doesn't seem to be fast enough for me. I was looking to use UDP and it seems WebRTC is the only way to do that from a browser. The caveat, it seems, is WebRTC is only PEER to PEER (browser to browser). I figured, I could use node webkit to emulate being my other "PEER". In my node app I could handle the "signaling" and have it set itself up in a RTCPeerConnection to my web app. Therefore, I could send my data from my web app to my node app (local network). For some context, I have one computer running native software to drive a light fixture and I want to use a web app to control the lights.

To boil the question down, how can I make a RTCPeerConnection from a browser to a node webkit app?

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-Jake

Answer (score 14):

[Node-RTCPeerConnection](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-rtc-peer-connection) is an attempt (<s>current WIP</s>) to create a spec compliant implementation of RTCPeerConnection for Node.js entirely in JavaScript with no native C or C++ code. This enables browser-peers to speak to non-browser (Node.js) peers.

But you can not use it for production yet.

---

Then we also have [wrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc) (node-webrtc) that provides a native module for NodeJS that supports a subset of standards-compliant WebRTC features. Specifically, the PeerConnection and DataChannel APIs.

Too many people are having problems with `wrtc`. Since it has to download lots of source and build it only to find out that it fails after a long while on certain platforms. Unfortunately it doesn't come with any prebuilt packages [described in this issue](https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc/issues/200)

---

You can use either the [google implementation of webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code) or a more recent implementation (by Ericsson) called [openWebrtc](http://www.openwebrtc.io/). The developers of openWebRTC are very proud of running their implementation on various pieces of hardware like raspberry pi and iOS devices.

---

The one that worked best for me was [electron-webrtc](https://github.com/mappum/electron-webrtc) (which in turn uses [electron-prebuilt](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt)) for better compatibility. It creates a hidden Electron process (which is based on Chromium, so WebRTC support is great!) and communicates with that process to enable WebRTC in Node.js. This adds a lot of overhead.

It is intended for use with RTCDataChannels, so the MediaStream API is not supported.

---

Other resources: 
https://github.com/webrtcftw/goals/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am having hard time to find a webrtc client for node.js

Comment: It seems the OpenWebRTC website was moved to https://www.openwebrtc.org/ -- it doesn't support node.js though! This project might help: https://github.com/ibc/mediasoup

Comment: Did anyone find any good solution for Node js RTCPeerConnection. Basically, I want to send a video stream from client to node, so that node can process the video stream live.

Answer (score 6):

Update 2019

Currently, the best and easiest way to solve this problem is to use [webrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc) module. Check [samples](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples) for inspiration. This module does what you were looking for, implemented with N-API and using Canvas module to compose new video from the client stream. Hopefully this will help those who face this problem in the future.